# Is negative $x$-axis not the locus of centers of circles touching the $y$-axis and circle $x^2+y^2-2x=0$ externally?

Tags: circles, conic-sections, locus

> Find the locus of the centre of circles touching the y-axis and circle $x^2+y^2-2x=0$ externally.

**My Attempt:**

Circle touching y-axis is $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=h^2$.

If this is to touch the given circle externally then the distance between their centres should be equal to the sum of their radii.

$$\sqrt{(h-1)^2+(k-0)^2}=h+1\\\implies h^2+1-2h+k^2=h^2+1+2h\\\implies k^2=4h$$

Thus, the locus is a right facing parabola passing through origin. $y^2=4x$

**But don't the circles $x^2+y^2+px=0, p\gt0$ also satisfy the given conditions?** i.e. they touch y-axis and touch the given circle externally.

So, shouldn't negative x-axis also be the locus?

Or, is it required that the every point of the given circle must be touched?

Comment: You are right. The locus is the **reunion** of the $y^2=4x$ parabola and the negative x axis

Comment: @Andrei thankyou very much